# How to append variable to Auth::user() and then save it and cache it?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, oauth, laravel-passport

I have the next problem: After auth user with Auth Passport provider in Laravel I get `Auth::user()`. Then I try to append variable to it.

```
 $role = Input::get('role');
 $user = Auth::user();
 $user->role = $role;
 Auth::setUser($user);`
```

It works well if use a new `$user` variable in current controller and route, but if I try to get `Auth::user()` in another route it returns old values. 
How to append variable to `Auth::user()` and then save it and cache it?
I want to change `Auth::user()` with "setUser" method and then cache it for use on all other routes. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `Auth::user()` its returning you the old value on other places is that `Auth::user()` is an authentication system that takes user credentails validates and then compare them agains the `User model` (aka default laravel auth)

With `setUser` you are just setting some properties when you new up the instance thats why in other places u get the old value which is being pulled from `User model` as in different places the `setUser` its unset.

Comment: Thanks! I note that next time it use User model. But, may be there are some way how I can resolve it and use Auth::user() component with new variables global. May be it will be some other effective construction like "_construct" in BaseController. Also the quastion how Laravel storing Auth::user() in cache, in session, or where? And during witch time it storing values?

Comment: @T.Abdullaev you don't need to change `Auth()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use append on User model for this,

for example,

```
protected $appends = [ 'my_role' => 1];
```